# Recurrence relation for a variant of knapsack problem?

Tags: c++, knapsack-problem

I am finding it difficult to understand two specific implementations which solve this problem on codeforces [link](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/189/A).

I understand this is similar to the knapsack problem. However when i solved it myself, i was not aware of the algorithm. I solved it from my own understanding of dynamic programming. My idea is to regard the remaining length of the ribbon as the next state. Here's my code

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(){
     int n,res1=0,res2,x=0;
     int a,b,c;
     cin >> n >> a >> b >> c;
     for(int i=0;i <= n/a; i++){
        res2 = -20000;
        for(int j=0; j <= (n-(a*i))/b; j++){
             x = (n - (a*i) - (b*j));
            res2=max(res2,(j + ((x % c) ? -10000 : x/c)));
        }
            res1=max(res1,i+res2);
     }
    cout << res1 << endl;
    return 0;
```

Implementation 1:

```
  1 #include <bits/stdc++.h>
  2 using namespace std;
  3 int main()
  4 {
  5         int f[4005],n,a,i,j;
  6         fill(f+1,f+4005,-1e9);
  7         cin>>n;
  8         for(;cin>>a;)
  9                 for(i=a;i<=n;i++)
 10                         f[i]=max(f[i],f[i-a]+1);
 11         cout<<f[n];
 12 }
```

Implementation 2:

```
  1 #include <bits/stdc++.h>
  2 int n, a, b, c, ost;
  3 std::bitset<4007> mog;
  4 main()
  5 {
  6         std::cin>>n>>a>>b>>c;
  7         mog[0]=1;
  8         for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
  9                 if ((mog=((mog<<a)|(mog<<b)|(mog<<c)))[n])
 10                         ost=i;
 11         std::cout << ost;
 12 }
```

Though i understand the general idea of solving the knapsack problem. I do not have a clear understanding of how lines 8,9,10 in Implementation 1 achieve this. Specifically irrespective of the input values of a,b,c the inner for loop is a single pass over the array for the corresponding value a received.

Similarly, I can see that lines 8,9,10 in implementation 2 does the same thing. But i have no clue at all how this piece of code works.

Please help me understand this. I feel there is some hidden structure to these two solutions which i am not seeing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First implementation is quite straightforward. It has inverted order of loops compared to your solution: outer loop goes through `a,b,c` and inner loop sets all elements in an array. But I can not understand how impl 2 work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Implementation 1

This is quite straightforward implementation of dynamic programming.

Outer loop just goes through three values: `a`, `b`, and `c`

```
  8         for(;cin>>a;)
```

Inner loop visits every element of an array and updates current best known number of cuts for given ribbon length.

```
  9                 for(i=a;i<=n;i++)
 10                         f[i]=max(f[i],f[i-a]+1);
```

---

#### Implementation 2

I don't think that it can be called dynamic programming, but the trick is quite neat.

It allocates array of bits with length equal to max `n`. Then sets one bit on the left. It means, that ribbon with length of 0 is a valid solution.
On each iteration algorithm shifts given array to the left by `a`, `b`, and `c`. Result of each such shift can be viewed as the new valid sizes of ribbon. By `or`ing result of all 3 shifts, we get all valid sizes after `i`'th cut. If `n`'th bit set we know ribbon of size `n` can be cut `i` times without remainder.

```
n = 10
a = 2
b = 3
c = 5

i=1:
0|0000000001 // mog
0|0000000100 // mog<<a
0|0000001000 // mog<<b
0|0000100000 // mog<<c
0|0000101100 // mog=(mog<<a)|(mog<<b)|(mog<<c)
^ here is a bit checked in 'if' statement '(mog=(...))[n]'
```

```
i=2:
0|0000101100 // mog
0|0010110000 // mog<<a
0|0101100000 // mog<<b
1|0110000000 // mog<<c // here we have solution with two pieces of size 5
1|0111110000 // (mog<<a)|(mog<<b)|(mog<<c)
^ now bit set, so we have a solution
```

We know that there is exactly `i` cuts at that point, so we set `ost=i`. But we found the worst solution, we have to keep going until we are sure that there is no more solutions.

Eventually we will reach this state:

```
i=5:
1|1100000000 // mog
1|0000000000 // mog<<a // 5 pieces of size 2
0|0000000000 // mog<<b
0|0000000000 // mog<<c
1|0000000000 // (mog<<a)|(mog<<b)|(mog<<c)
```

Here it is the last time when bit at position `n` will be set. So we will set `ost=5` and will do some more iterations.

Algorithm uses `n` as upper bound of possible cuts, but it's obvious that this bound can be improved. For example `n / min({a,b,c})` should be sufficient.